# C# - How to create a pop up message once timer reaches zero

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-code

I am creating a game in visual studio using c sharp and want to add a pop up message saying 'game Over' once the timer reaches 0. Currently the countdown timer goes to negative seconds and the game keeps going. Currently attempt is below and any help is apricated.

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _random = new Random();   // r is my random number generator
        _countDown = 30;
        SetUpMyTimers();// method for my timer
        endGame();
    }

    private void endGame()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void SetUpMyTimers() // calling my method 
    {
        // start a timer to run a method every 1000ms
        // that method is "TimerFunctions" that runs on the UI thread
        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000), () =>
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            { TimerFunctions(); });
            return true;
        });
    }
    private void TimerFunctions()
    {
        // change the countdown.
        _countDown--;
        LblCountdown.Text = _countDown.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: What class is `Device`? Does the countdown work already? If so, what prevents you from adding a condition when `_countDown` reaches zero?

Answer (score 1):

The countdown is over to call the function.Use winform timer control to implement countdown function

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    TimeSpan Span = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
       
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Span = Span.Subtract(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1));
        label1.Text = Span.Hours.ToString() + ":" + Span.Minutes.ToString() + ":" + Span.Seconds.ToString();//时间格式0：0：10
        if (Span.TotalSeconds < 0.0)//when the countdown is over
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            MessageBox.Show("game over");
        }

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Interval = 1000;//Set every interval to 1 second
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        MessageBox.Show("End the game after 10s");

    }
}
```

Test timer:

[image]
Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following code.

```
<Grid>
        <TextBlock Name="tbTime" />
    </Grid>
```

Codebehind:

```
DispatcherTimer _timer;
        TimeSpan _time;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

            _timer = new DispatcherTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1), DispatcherPriority.Normal, delegate
            {
                tbTime.Text = _time.ToString("c");
                if (_time == TimeSpan.Zero)
                {
                    _timer.Stop();
                    MessageBox.Show("GameOver");
                   
                } 
                _time = _time.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(-1));
            }, Application.Current.Dispatcher);

            _timer.Start();
        }
```

The result:

[image]